# Move to nearby grid point

Tags: java, swing, random, grid, windowbuilder

I'm using java and window builder
I have a 4x4 grid on my jframe made out of jlabels. I can press a button and it displays an image (red.png) at a random grid point.

How can I make it so that

Comment: Does the name of the image mean you should add the homework tag?  :)

Answer (score 1):

The image will likely be displayed as an ImageIcon.

- Use a 2 dimensionaly array of JLabel held by your JPanel in its GridLayout.
- When a button is pushed, find the JLabel with the red Icon, a for loop will work well for this. You can simply get the icon from the JLabel in the loop and see if it equals the of interest, here I'll call the redDiskIcon.
- Remove the Icon by calling `setIcon(null)`
- Then use a for loop to find a new location and set the icon via `setIcon(redDiskIcon)`.

Note that most of this is unnecessary:

```
JLabel b = new JLabel("");      
panel.add(a);

JLabel b = new JLabel("");      
panel.add(b);

JLabel c = new JLabel("");      
panel.add(c);

final JLabel d = new JLabel("");        
panel.add(d);

JLabel e = new JLabel("");      
panel.add(e);
```

Just use a for loop to create your JLabels and add them to the grid JPanel and to your JLabel array. No need for variables a, b, c, d,... and in fact many reasons not to have these variables.

Comment: a `for` loop is not actually needed to find the grid point of the label. `GridLayout` with left-right can tell the index of the component: `(row-1)*gridLayout.getColumns() + col-1` in the list of components of the Container. Though, i am sure you know it ;)

Comment: thanks for the comments.  I do it this way when I place the circle to any random point. What I'm wanting to know how to do is, move the circle ONLY to neighbouring points. Not any grid point.

Comment: @user1300788: that would involve a little basic math and logic that you can solve quickly with pencil and paper. I am betting that you're up to figuring this out on your own.

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea? :S I'm not very good at programming sorry

Comment: @user1300788: Don't give up so easily. Let's at least see your best attempt as an edit to your question above.

Comment: @user1300788: note that there are many possible solutions. One is to create an `ArrayList<JLabel>`, put the candidate JLabel positions into this List, shuffle the list via `Collections.shuffle(...)` and then pick out the bottom item.